# chunk option defaults in child documents

Tags: r, r-markdown

I setup of several chunk defaults in my setup chunk, such as the `connection` for `sql` chunks so that I don't have to retype it for every sql chunk. My document is getting a little long, so I want to break it up into child documents, but as far as I can tell I now need to explicitly name the connection with `{sql, connection=maindb}` when I want to run the chunk individually using the play button.

---

````
# main.Rmd

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
maindb <- conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(connection = "maindb")
```

```{sql default-connection}
SELECT * FROM Person -- this works
```

```{sql explicit-connection, connection=maindb}
SELECT * FROM Person -- this works
```

```{r, child='child.Rmd'}
```
````

---

````
# child.Rmd

```{sql child-default-connection}
SELECT * FROM Person -- this does not work
```

```{sql child-explicit-connection, connection=maindb}
SELECT * FROM Person -- this works
```
````

After running the setup chunk, I can run all the individual sql chunks by clicking the green "play" button in RStudio, except for child-default-connection, which complains the `connection` parameter is not set.